# Ping и Tracert

Tags: tracert, ping

Почему когда пингуешь удалённый сервак время сотстовляет 40 мс, а когда делаешь трассировку, сумма времени на каждом узле гораздо больше пинга!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что при трассировке сперва отправляется обычный ICMP (ping) на хост, при этом TTL = 1, соответственно самый ближайший ваш маршрутизатор пришлет вам обратный ответ, что TTL маловат, и вы не достигнете адресата. Собственно при этом считается время от запроса до ответа. Затем TTL увеличивается на 1 и уже второй маршрутизатор отправит вам ответ, а это еще больше времени. И так далее, пока с увеличением TTL вы не дойдете до вашего хоста и при этом суммарное время отклика будет = сумме времени отклика до каждого из маршрутизаторов, а последнее время отклика (когда достигли хост) будет примерно равно обычному пингу.

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Интересно кто заминусовал @dex ?

Comment: Соседние темы посмотрите)

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь всё ясно! А каким образом засекается и считается время?

Comment: У меня вопрос по поводу этого же: а почему тогда если я пингую те-же узлы то примерно то же время получается? А иногда прямой пинг даже больше?

Comment: @rejie берется время от запуска пинга до получения ответа, берется время с высокой точностью. @Сергей не понял вопроса.

Comment: Ну я беру tracert до определенного узла, потом беру и прямым пингом стучусь на узел с наибольшим пингом. Его время примерно такое же получается, причем пинг иногда даже больше.

Comment: "TTL = 1, соответственно самый ближайший ваш маршрутизатор пришлет вам обратный ответ, что TTL маловат" А откуда он узнает сколько времени прошло после отправки на него пакета? Для этого по идее все системные часы должны быть синхронизхированны с точностью до миллисекунд!?

Comment: Да и я встретил еще тот факт что до некоторых узлов я не могу допинговать, значит они во внутренней сети. Что значит что пинг делает ближайший маршрутизатор. И я предполагаю что он сначало разберется с TTL а потом уже отправит данные о пинге. Или я не прав?

Comment: @rejie, TTL - это не время как таковое, а это число промежуточных хостов (маршрутизаторов), каждый маршрутизатор при получении пакета, обновляет значение TTL, вычитая из него 1. Поэтому когда получается 0, то отправляется сообщение, что TTL исчерпано и дальше пакет передаваться не может. Собственно на основе данного факта и построена трассировка.

Comment: @Сергей до некоторых узлов вы не можете "допинговаться" так как у них запрещены ICMP ответы, но трафик они пропускают, поэтому может случиться так, что некоторые маршрутизаторы в последовательности маркируются звездочками.

Comment: Проблема в том что они не отмечены звездочкам, но допинговаться до них я не могу.

Comment: Насчет TTL: "В IPv4 TTL представляет собой восьмиразрядное поле IP-заголовка. Оно находится в девятом октете из двадцати. Значение TTL может рассматриваться как верхняя граница времени существования IP-дейтаграммы в сети. Поле TTL устанавливается отправителем дейтаграммы, и уменьшается каждым узлом (например, маршрутизатором) на пути его следования, в соответствии со временем пребывания в данном устройстве или согласно протоколу обработки.". Т.е. по википедии не на 1 а на определенное время (либо как задано протоколом, возможно действительно на 1).

Comment: @Сергей ICMP-request имеет несколько типов. И каждый из типов можно запретить на маршрутизаторе. А тип ответа о TTL отличается от обычного пинга.

Comment: Я видел что они разные в той же статье про TTL написано что можно вернуть ICMP 11 - истечение времени. Но это в любом случае не отвечает на то почему tracert может допинговаться а я нет, при условии что пакеты от ping и tracert одинаковые.

Comment: Пакеты одинаковые, а пакеты-ответы разные. для ТТЛ - Type: 11 (Time-to-live exceeded), для обычного пинга Type: 0 (Echo (ping) reply). Значит на маршрутизаторе разрешено выдавать тип 11, т.к. это системный ICMP и он нужен для многих целей, а ответ на пинг давать запрещено.

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь что на маршрутизаторах стоит блок определенных ICMP пакетов, гораздо проще(и менее затратнее) просто блокировать ICMP запросы. Я полагаю что все же пинг идет от ближайшего узла или маскируется под него. На днях попробую на packet tracer'е воспроизвести ситуацию.

Comment: Стоит, чтобы он вообще не пинговался ибо это не нужно. А все блокировать нельзя, сообщение о том, что TTL тю-тю необходимо для некоторых приложений, а есть еще масса всяких ICMP типов, предназначенных для маршрутизации. ICMP v6 для IPv6 вообще штука незаменимая, сеть работать не будет без нее.

Comment: Ну насколько я знаю сейчас не очень то распространен ipv6. Да кстати насчет непингуемости некоторых узлов забыл сказать что возвращается "не удается обнаружить узел". И пожалуй еще один момент по поводу этой теории: пинг отправляет пакеты не сразу а после ответа предыдущего, тогда по логике он должен только один раз принять TTL нужного значения и уже 2й и 3й пакеты должны придти с меньшим временем.

Comment: Не понимаю ваших коментариев иногда. Он посылает пакет несколько раз, чтобы удостовериться, что пинг проходит нормально. "Не удается обнаружить узел" - есть такой тип ответа, а еще есть "заданный порт недоступен" и т.п. Вот полный список, и работает это именно на фаерволе http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/#ICMPTYPES изучайте. Простите, но по-моему, вы много чего путаете.

Comment: Нет тут явно запрос на dns сервер обламывается в процессе пинга. Дело не ICMP пакете.

Comment: Как такое может быть если вы даже получаете ICMP ответ? У вас точно каша в голове. Или вы описываете все не правильно.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что "Не удается обнаружить узел" это именно ICMP ответ? Это ответ от DNS сервера на запрос IP из имени.

Comment: Потому, что вы не сказали какими инструментами пользуетесь, для отправки ICMP запросов. Вы пытались пинговать какой-то маршрутизатор, а на кой ему ДНС? Собственно и сложилось такое впечатление.

Comment: Ещё для затравки: tracert бывають разные. Вместо ICMP вполне могут использоваться пакеты UDP с увеличивающимся TTL. :))

Comment: Я пользовался обычным консольным ping. Перед тем как пинговать он обычно пытается получить IP чтобы знать куда пакеты слать. tracert тоже обычный консольный.

Comment: Так надо было сказать, я уж думал, что вы пользовались снифером и там получили ТТЛ и сообщение.

Comment: Нет ответ от самой утилиты) Так что я думаю это достаточное доказательство того, что пакеты ICMP от tracert идут по туннелю до нужного узла (вариант насчет ближайших точек маршрута не сходится из информации в вики, разве что запрос от ближайшего, а ответ уже вам).
А сниффером я как раз ловил пакеты от пинга и трасерта, чтобы проверить ICMP пакеты (одинаковы ли они), но что-то у меня на виртуалке не срослось с сетевым интерфейсом, так что я пока отложил это.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что когда вы пингуете удаленный узел ваш пакет идет через "туннель" и считается ими как обычный траффик. В случае же трасерта ваши пакеты проходят через линейку маршрутизаторов (на это указывает то что нельзя пропинговать некоторые узлы на маршруте). Дальше просто цитата из википедии:

> В силу особенностей работы протоколов маршрутизации в сети Интернет, обратные маршруты часто не совпадают с прямыми, причем это справедливо для всех промежуточных узлов в трейсе. Поэтому, ICMP ответ от каждого промежуточного узла может идти своим собственным маршрутом, затеряться или прийти с большой задержкой, хотя в реальности с пакетами которые адресованы конечному узлу этого не происходит. Кроме того, на промежуточных маршрутизаторах часто стоит ограничение числа ответов ICMP в единицу времени, что приводит к появлению ложных потерь.

[Ссылка на статью про tracert](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)